# What/if "render()" needs to do 'work' (not be 100% pure?)

Tags: reactjs

I understand that render() should be pure. Imagine you create a component that displays/renders the contents of some system or database object.  The object is passed as a param. Over time, another activity changes which object is passed to that component, or changes something about the object.  When render() is called, it detects it needs more data which might mean another fetch() and needs to wait for that data before it can display/render.

I dont know how best to handle this.  didMount() helps on the FIRST use of the component, but not if the object updates somehow (other activities) and/or its now a new/different object for the active component.

For now, in render() I queue the fetch() and return a busy-wheel and later when the data arrives I change 'state' so the component re-renders and now with all the data it needs.  But this I doubt is a pure approach.

I'm sure this is a very common scenario and thus there is some correct way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a usecase where different activities maybe associated with your component and hence you have difficulty managing them. There are couple of ways to resolve this, with the most easiest and well maintainable being, split your core component logic as:

- Components : Stateless components which care only about the view. i.e, Given some data it will render a UI. It does not care where the data arrives from or who fetches it. It always renders the same UI for the same data, hence called pure component. All interactions happen through event handlers, and the component itself should have no business logic stored.
- Containers : Components which are responsible for fetching and maintaining the data for an activity. These are responsible for making the actual network calls and managing the state of the data. Based on the data, the container mounts a pure component with the data and event handlers passed as props.

If you have a large number of activities, you can always make multiple containers for each activity.

By this way you would have clear separation of concerns and would be easy to maintain. The same component can be used by multiple containers if they have same UI.

I would suggest reading this [article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Answer (score 0):

First of all think about any React Component as some code supporting rendering. React is considered *View* in Model-View-Controller architecture style. So everything happening in React Component is heppening to support rendering. In general you component should know everithing about object which it will render and request everything needed for rendering in advance (for example in response to some button click or using some interval)

You may consider dividing you app to presentation components and container components (as Redux [suggests](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#designing-component-hierarchy), even if you're not going to use Redux)

First design presentation components that will only render UI based on props.

For example

```
export function PresetationOfObject (porps) {
    return <div>My object is {props.myObject.toString()}</div>
}
```

Don't fetch anything here. You may render conditionally based on received props, but not request any new data.

Container component on the other hand, will fetch everything required for rendering. It should *own* object that will be rendered. By owning I mean that object originates at container component and container component knows everything about possible changes of Object.

Mostly object (or any other data) changes in response to user actions so when user clicks some button, container component will refetch data.

For example

```
export class ContainerOfObject extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            object = {}
        }
        this.refreshObject();
    }

    async refreshObject () {
        let newObject = await get('http://backend.com/object');
        this.setState ({ object: newObject });
    }

    handleClieck () {
        refreshObject();
    }

    render () {
        return <div>
            <PresetationOfObject object={this.state.object}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Update object</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> didMount() helps on the FIRST use of the component, but not if the
>   object updates somehow (other activities) and/or its now a
>   new/different object for the active component.

Use `componentDidUpdate()` which triggers after every update to data except the first.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate